# Print out items from a list using random.choices in a for loop without brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, random

I'm currently working on an word encrypter and I wanted a letter to have multiple "translations", so I made lists for each letter contaning different translations. Using a for loop and the **random module**, I am able to check and replace the letters from an input with a random character from the letter's list. Example:

```
import random

d= ["°", "┌", "Ï"]
o= ["‗", "‥", "ӟ"]
word = "do"
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i]=="d":
        print(random.choices(d), end="")
    if word[i]=="o":
        print(random.choices(o), end="")
```

This code is going to replace the letters with a random character from their respective list.
Here is the problem: the output of the random choices in **brackets** (it outputs `['°']['‥']` instead of `°‥`). Is there any way to remove the brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.choice()` instead. `choices()` is for more than one choice, so that's why it returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*` list unpacking operator. This will unpack the list or get all the elements from the list

```
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i]=="d":
        print(*random.choices(d), end="")
    if word[i]=="o":
        print(*random.choices(o), end="")
```

Alternatively, use `random.choice` instead of `random.choices` because `random.choice` returns a **string** and `random.choices` returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

`random.choises` returns an array of `k` choises. when `k` isn't passed to the `random.choises` function, it defaults to 1. You can use `random.coise` instead to just get back the value of one of the elements in the list.

Comment: It is ```choice``` and not ```choise```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"".join(random.choices(d))` inside the print statement to convert it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other answers already have mentioned, `random.choices` always returns a list, even if it's just a list of one item. The function you're looking for is `random.choice`, which returns just one item from the given collection.

My suggestion would be to use a dictionary to map individual characters to a collection of characters to choose from. In my case I chose tuples, but they could be lists. They could even be just strings:

```
from random import choice

mapping = {
    "d": ("1", "2", "3"),
    "o": ("a", "b", "c")
}

print("".join(choice(mapping[char]) for char in "dodo"))
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using randint instead of choices. It would look somthing like this

```
print(d[random.randint(0, len(d))
```

So all together it would look like this

```
d= ["°", "┌", "Ï"]
o= ["‗", "‥", "ӟ"]
word = "do"
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i]=="d":
        print(d[random.randint(0, len(d))
    if word[i]=="o":
        print(o[random.randint(0, len(o))
```